# mysql crashing on amazon linux ami

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2

I keep starting up mysql and then it crashes a couple of minutes later. Can anyone decipher this error log?

```
0328 17:09:13 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
130328 17:09:13 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
130328 17:09:13 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
130328 17:09:13 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.5
130328 17:09:13 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
130328 17:09:13 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
130328 17:09:13 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
InnoDB: The first specified data file ./ibdata1 did not exist:
InnoDB: a new database to be created!
130328 17:09:13  InnoDB: Setting file ./ibdata1 size to 10 MB
InnoDB: Database physically writes the file full: wait...
130328 17:09:13  InnoDB: Log file ./ib_logfile0 did not exist: new to be created
InnoDB: Setting log file ./ib_logfile0 size to 5 MB
InnoDB: Database physically writes the file full: wait...
130328 17:09:13  InnoDB: Log file ./ib_logfile1 did not exist: new to be created
InnoDB: Setting log file ./ib_logfile1 size to 5 MB
InnoDB: Database physically writes the file full: wait...
InnoDB: Doublewrite buffer not found: creating new
InnoDB: Doublewrite buffer created
InnoDB: 127 rollback segment(s) active.
InnoDB: Creating foreign key constraint system tables
InnoDB: Foreign key constraint system tables created
130328 17:09:14  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
130328 17:09:15 InnoDB: 5.5.30 started; log sequence number 0
130328 17:09:15 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '0.0.0.0'; port: 3306
130328 17:09:15 [Note]   - '0.0.0.0' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
130328 17:09:15 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
130328 17:09:15 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
130328 17:09:15 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.30'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
130401 17:03:23 mysqld_safe Number of processes running now: 0
130401 17:03:24 mysqld_safe mysqld restarted
130401 17:03:55 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
130401 17:04:08 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
130401 17:04:08 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
130401 17:04:08 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.5
130401 17:04:08 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
130401 17:04:11 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
InnoDB: mmap(137363456 bytes) failed; errno 12
130401 17:04:11 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
```

Comment: What size instance are you running? Seems like its not able to allocate memory to the innodb buffer pool.

Comment: Micro is limited to 613 MB of memory, im not sure if swap space is configured by default for it. Likely you will need to tweak your mysql settings to fit the memory footprint.

Comment: @datasage I upped from micro to small and everything's good! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ec2 instance is too small for mysql and is limited to 613MB of memory.